# ZAP setup for selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, owasp, zap

Im trying to set up OWASP ZAP to work with my selenium tests.

```
public class ZapScanTest {
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ZapScanTest.class.getName());
private final static String ZAP_PROXYHOST = "127.0.0.1";
private final static int ZAP_PROXYPORT = 8080;
private final static String ZAP_APIKEY = null;

// Change this to the appropriate driver for the OS, alternatives in the drivers directory
private final static String CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "drivers/chromedriver.exe";
private final static String MEDIUM = "MEDIUM";
private final static String HIGH = "HIGH";
private ScanningProxy zapScanner;
private Spider zapSpider;
private WebDriver driver;
private Login login;
private final static String[] policyNames = {"directory-browsing","cross-site-scripting","sql-injection","path-traversal","remote-file-inclusion","server-side-include",
        "script-active-scan-rules","server-side-code-injection","external-redirect","crlf-injection"};
int currentScanID;


@Before
public void setup() {
    zapScanner = new ZAProxyScanner(ZAP_PROXYHOST,ZAP_PROXYPORT,ZAP_APIKEY);
    zapScanner.clear(); //Start a new session
    zapSpider = (Spider)zapScanner;
    log.info("Created client to ZAP API");
    driver = DriverFactory.createProxyDriver("chrome",createZapProxyConfigurationForWebDriver(), CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
    myApp = new MyAppNavigation(driver);
    myApp.registerUser(); //Doesn't matter if user already exists, bodgeit just throws an error
}

@After
public void after() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void testSecurityVulnerabilitiesLogin() {
    login.navigateToLogin();
    log.info("Spidering...");
    spiderWithZap();
    login.navigateToLogin();

    setAlertAndAttackStrength();
    zapScanner.setEnablePassiveScan(true);
    scanWithZap();

    List<Alert> alerts = filterAlerts(zapScanner.getAlerts());
    logAlerts(alerts);
    assertThat(alerts.size(), equalTo(0));
}
```

However i keep getting the eorror: 
    org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApiException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Anybody got any help in how to set up one of these as im having real trouble getting it to run on my website on my device

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled the API key in ZAP? If not you will fail to connect.

You can set the ZAP API key via the command line using:

> -config api.key=change-me-9203935709

You will then need to specify it in your script above.

If you have done that then look in the zap.log file for any error messages.

Comment: Wow thanks for the help, seems very difficult to get any, is there a way to disable the api key? How do i set the api key in windows? I know the questions are very simplistic Im finding it really tough to get going on this, im used to just automating web applications

Comment: Yes, you can disable the key using the command line option: "-config api.disablekey=true" - details on the FAQ: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQapikey

Comment: You can also set it via the desktop GUI in the Options / API screen, but as you are using ZAP for automation I assumed you would be using ZAP in daemon mode :)

Comment: Oh, and re getting help we do have a ZAP user group which is linked off the ZAP websites and off the ZAP desktop 'Online' menu - thats pretty active. We also have an irc channel we use - details on the ZAP repo...

Comment: Haha I am literally trying to set it up without any prior knowledge. I have been using zap for about a week and manually its ok, its not a huge site so would like to just try to active scan the pages while logged in/out, different users,etc. Ive not got any prior experience in this area so "daemon mode" doesnt mean anything to me :D

Comment: Thanks for the links to help groups. Being a newbie to these things can be pretty harsh. Im only a simple automation tester